# MATLAB - create anonymous function recursively

Tags: matlab

For use within the least square fitting routine `lsqcurvefit`, I need a function in terms of a series representation like :

```
F = @(D, t) F0 - D(1)*(1-exp(-t))...
               - D(2)*(1-exp(-t))...
               - D(3)*(1-exp(-t))...
                ...
               - D(n)*(1-exp(-t));
```

However, the amount of terms in the series is to be determined by the user; so the anonymous function F needs to be created within a loop, like

```
F = @(D, t) F0;
for i=1:n
    F = F - D(i)*(1-exp(-t));
end
```

Unfortunately, the above method is not working within MATLAB; is there a possibility to get it work?

Comment: Why do you want to make an anonymous function out of this?

Comment: I need to use it for the 'lsqcurvefit' function; therefore it needs to be an anonymous function

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something greatly, according to the documentation it should work just fine with a normal function file: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html#inputarg_fun

Comment: Just make a separate file and put whatever you want there as a function.

Comment: You can make a function handle to a normal function; it doesn't have to be an anonymous function.

Comment: OK, so I totally misunderstood something... Now it works great; thanks!

Comment: You *do* realize that you can write this as `F0 - sum(D*(1-exp(-t)))`? That's for scalar `t`; if `t` is a vector with the same dimensions as `D`, then it reduces to `F0 - D*(1-exp(-t).')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a combination of anonymous and normal functions.

```
recursionDepth = 5
CoefficientList = ones(numel(recursionDepth) + 1);

functionResults = @(t) myFunction(t, CoefficientList, recursionDepth);

function F = myFunction(t, CoefficientList, Depth)
   F = CoefficientList(1);
   for idx = 1:Depth
      F = CoefficientList(idx) * (1 - exp(-1));
   end
end
```

What I've done here is defined the full function that contains your model with all of its parameters, and then wrapped that into an anonymous function that sets the user selectable, unchanging parameters within the anonymous function, and leaves the single adjustable parameter as the input. You'll have to adjust for your particular model, but that is your basic template.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your function is not actually recursive. You can just do:

```
F = @(D,t) F0 - sum(D*(1-exp(-t));
```

or, if you want to specify `n` explicitly:

```
F = @(D,n,t) F0 - sum(D(1:n)*(1-exp(-t));
```

or, if `t` is a vector the same size as `D`:

```
F = @(D,n,t) F0 - D(1:n)*(1-exp(-t(1:n)).';
```